# GitLab - Update private project dependent on public project

Tags: gitlab

Assuming that there is a public project `publicProject`. And you have got your own private Project `privateProject`.

Is there a way to automatically trigger a CI/CD pipeline wihin `privateProject` every time `publicProject` receives a new push? Note, that although `publicProject` is public, there is no way to modify the pipeline within `publicProject` - so no trigger would be possible.

Are there any chances this could be possible?

Answer (score 0):

If no trigger is possible, you might need, as a workaround, to schedule your own pipline (see "[Configuring pipeline schedules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html)") in order to:

- pull the public repository
- check if new commits have been done

The last fetched commit could be cached (see [Caching in GitLab CI/CD](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/caching/)) in a file which can persists between subsequent jobs.